# Render ES6 component is not working in codepen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, es6-class

```
class Puppies extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <DIV />
        <JSX />
        <aClassDiv />
    </div>
    );
  };

};
ReactDOM.render(<Puppies/>, document.getElementById("body-text"));
```

the above is not rendering, but it also does not show an error.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/Logan_code/pen/BaLMwdX)

Comment: On your codepen, the console does show errors: _"Error: Minified React error #130; visit (...) for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment (...)"_.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The way you are using them is as Class or Functional Component. But actually JSX expects an expression from you like {YOUR_EXPRESSION}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your components don't return anything.

```
const DIV =(
    <div>
        <h2>I'm a Sub-heading :|</h2>
        <p>text is what I am...</p>
    </div>
);

const JSX = (
  <div>
    <h2>There is more!</h2>
    <p>Words go here...</p>
  </div>
);

const aClassDiv = (
  <div className ="myDiv">
    <h1>Im in a class!</h1>
    <p>you dont know my class...</p>
  </div>
);
```

This is your code, it should be this way:

```
   const DIV = () => {
  return (
      <div>
        <h2>I'm a Sub-heading :|</h2>
        <p>text is what I am...</p>
    </div>
  )
}
  


const JSX = () => {
  return  (
     <div>
      <h2>There is more!</h2>
      <p>Words go here...</p>
     </div>
  )
}
 


const aClassDiv = () => {
 return (
    <div className ="myDiv">
    <h1>Im in a class!</h1>
    <p>you dont know my class...</p>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, once i changed them to return and the "aClassDiv" (wasn't being picked up by the custom tags). everything works now

Answer (score 0):

Call them like this.

```
    const DIV =(
        <div>
            <h2>I'm a Sub-heading :|</h2>
            <p>text is what I am...</p>
        </div>
    );
    
    const JSX = (
      <div>
        <h2>There is more!</h2>
        <p>Words go here...</p>
      </div>
    );
    
    const aClassDiv = (
      <div className ="myDiv">
        <h1>Im in a class!</h1>
        <p>you dont know my class...</p>
      </div>
    );
    
    class Puppies extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      };
    
      render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {DIV}
           {aClassDiv}
            {JSX}
        </div>
        );
      };
    
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<Puppies/>, document.getElementById("body-text"))

;
```